# Using getPerspective in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, perspective

I have an image that I want to stretch to cover the entire screen after transformation.

My code is as such:

```
src = np.array([[0, 0], [997, 102], [1000, 600], [0, 995]], np.float32)
dst = np.array([[0, 0], [997, 0], [1000, 995], [0, 995]], np.float32)
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst)
warped = cv2.warpPerspective(img, M, (1000, 1000))
```

where the `src` coordinates refer to the 4 red points in the image, in clockwise order.

The `dst` coordinates refer to the 2 red points on the left, and the 2 blue points on the right of the image, in clockwise order.

The idea is that I want to "stretch" the image such that the 2 red points on the right correspond to the 2 blue points.

[image]

However, the `warped` image turns out to be:

[image]

Is there something I did wrong, or assumed wrongly about the usage of the functions?

Comment: you can use cv2.findHomography() function to transform between the red and blue points. Refer to [this site](https://www.learnopencv.com/homography-examples-using-opencv-python-c/)

Comment: I can't reproduce your result. With your code I'm getting correct output.

Comment: @AlekseyPetrov That's strange. Could you share your result?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your output (Windows, Python 3, OpenCV 3.1):

Using this image as input:

[image: input]

Using your code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("input.jpg")

src = np.array([[0, 0], [997, 102], [1000, 600], [0, 995]], np.float32)
dst = np.array([[0, 0], [997, 0], [1000, 995], [0, 995]], np.float32)

M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst)
warped = cv2.warpPerspective(img, M, (1000, 1000))

cv2.imwrite("output.jpg", warped)
```

I get this output:

[image: output]

So, the code that you provided is correct. You should look for errors in the rest of your code or your environment.